# VDI - No Virtual Desktop Templates (Windows server 2012 R2 )

Tags: hyper-v, rds, vdi

http://postimg.org/image/y1kkx3j6z/

I setting up the RDS role for VDI. I plan to have a personal virtual desktops.
When i get to the step to select the Virtual Desktop Template, nothing shows up in the list. I have already installed and sys prepped a Windows 8 Enterprise x64 VM
i have also tried:
remove/reinstall all RDS roles, 
Generation 1 in hyper-v

Answer (score 1):

You have to Export the Template

Shut Down -> Right Click "export" to a location

Refresh and go through the steps again